# UTM params for GA4 measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

How do I send UTM params or any campaign data to google analytics 4 using measurement protocol? Their GA4 documentation does not mention anything about this.

Comment: Are UTM params supported in GA4?

Comment: @DaImTo their documentation does not have it. but shouldn't they have already thought about this? i did not find anything about this anywhere in the internet

Comment: First off GA4 is still beta, second if its not documented then its not supported Google only documents things that are supported.  Remember GA4 is nothing like universal analytics you cant compare these systems.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing the [Measurement Protocol (Google Analytics 4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4)  is still in beta.

[image]

There are limitations in what it supports and what it will support in the future.

[image]

UTM parameters are text strings that you can append to URLs that allow you track those URLs when they get clicked on. UTM parameters make Universal analytics Google Analytics pick up on the data in the code and log it with the pageview. The resulting data is visible in Universal analytics Google Analytics, meaning you can track traffic in terms of where it came from and how it got to you.

At the time of writing there is no mention of UTM support in Google analytics GA4